Variance for a renewal-reward process
Referring to the renewal-reward random process, and using the notation therein, is there anything we can say about the variance of the total reward $ Y_t $? For an ordinary renewal process, we have a central limit theorem as given here, but there seems to be no analogous formula for the case with rewards.
I am coming at this as a non-expert in probability theory/statistics so here was my naive attempt:
When time $ t $ is large, so that $ X_t $ is also large, from the definition $ Y_t = \sum_{i=1}^{X_t} W_i $, the sum of these variables will be approximately normally distributed (by the simple central limit theorem) with mean $ X_t \cdot E[W] $ and variance $ X_t \cdot Var[W] $. This is probably wrong actually, since the number of samples $ X_t $ is not deterministic but is itself a random variable. Intuitively I guess this would create additional variance (uncertainty) in the reward $ Y_t $. But perhaps $ \lim_{t \rightarrow \infty} Var[Y_t] \geq E[X_t] \cdot Var[W] $ is a reasonable guess, and using the CLT for $ X_t $ gives $ \lim_{t \rightarrow \infty} \frac{Var[Y_t]}{t} \geq \frac{Var[W]}{E[S]} $.
Similar question with no answers: here (tail probabilities)
